# Restricted database user for Django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, security

I'm running Django with Postgres database. On top of application-level security checks, I'm considering adding database-level restrictions. E.g. the application code should only be able to INSERT into log tables, and not UPDATE or DELETE from them.

I would manually create database user with appropriate grants for this. I would also need a more powerful user for running database migrations.

My question is, do people practice things like this? Any advice, best practices on using restricted database users with Django?

**Edit**: To clarify, there's no technical problem, I'm just interested to hear other people's experiences and takeaways. One Django-specific thing is, I'll need at least two DB users: for normal operation and for running migrations. Where do I store credentials for the more privileged user? Maybe make `manage.py migrate` prompt for password?

As for the reasoning, suppose my app has a SQL injection vulnerability. With privileged user, the attacker can do things like drop all tables. With a more limited user there's slightly less damage potential and afterwards there's some evidence in insert-only log tables.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about programming, at least within the scope of StackOverflow. Recommending libraries and off-site resources is off-topic.

Comment: This is "How to do 'X' with Django? Is it even a sensible idea to try do 'X' with Django?" type of a question. Is there a StackExchange site better suited for this question?

Comment: I don't think there's a better SE site. Chat might be helpful in either getting an answer, or in rewriting the question to be more topical.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you want to add database-level restrictions, than do it. That has nothing to do with Django. Personally I don't see the reasoning, because your app should decide who gets to control what, and Django's security checks should be sufficient, and even if not there are plenty of libraries that extend the basic authentication backend and gives you more control. That being said, adding security checks on db-level will probably just mean you'd have to deal with any problems you'll have managing your database with django

Answer (score 6):

The way I would try to solve this problem is:

- Setup two database connection for the same database but different users:

  1. 'default' for unprivileged db user.
  2. 'master' for user with full access to the db.
- Configure routers to your liking: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/
- Perform migrations: `./manage.py migrate --database=master`

Now that being said, if you have a vulnerability, like a SQL injection, even with a user that can read, it is already a disaster. If you have db backup setup, you shouldn't worry about lost/corrupted data, you should be worrying about data leakage!

On the other hand, there might be other use cases for the proposed problem.

Answer (score 1):

For storing the credentials to the privileged user for management commands, when running manage.py you can use the `--settings` flag, which you would point to another settings file that has the other database credentials.

Example migrate command using the new settings file:

`python manage.py migrate --settings=myapp.privileged_settings`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is practiced sometimes, but not commonly. The best way to do it is to grant specific privileges on user, not in django. Making such restrictions means that we should not trust application, because it might change some files / data in db in the way that we do not expect it to do so.

So, to sum up: create another user able to create / modify data and user another one with restrictions to use normally.

It's also quite common in companies to create one user to insert data and another one for employees / scripts to access it.